# Angular 10 RxJs compare observable with non observable

Tags: angular

How to compare selected by user inputKind that has type `Kind`. With `randomKind$` that has type: `Observable<Kind>`?

**Html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <ng-container *ngIf="((kindViewModel$ | async)?.kinds) as kinds">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>{{(randomKind$ | async).originalText}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div *ngFor="let kind of kinds">
                    <h3>
                        <button mat-button (click)="kindSelected(kind)">{{kind.translatedText}}</button>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
  public randomKind$: Observable<Kind> = this.kindsService.kindViewModel$
    .pipe(map(t => t.kinds[this.randomInt(0, 7)]));

  public kindSelected(inputKind: Kind) {
      //how to compare inputKind with randomKind?
  }

 export interface Kind {
    originalQuestions: string;
    originalText: string;
    translatedQuestions: string;
    translatedText: string;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `randomKind$` and listen for values. Store the newest value in another property. Let's name it `theVal`

```
this.randomKind$.subscribe((x) => { this.theVal = x });
```

Compare with the new `theVal`.

An alternative maybe [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject). Since it has a `getValue` method, you get read the most recent value anytime.